# Add a category to the permalink for wordpress page only

Tags: wordpress

My permalink structure in WordPress is /%postname%/ which I do not want to change.

I'm trying to add a page (not a post) and create a permalink like:

```
http://example.com/non-existing-category/my-page-title/
```

But wordpress changes it to `http://example.com/non-existing-category-my-page-title/`

It removes the slash between the category and page title.

Without changing the site's permalink structure, how can I force the permalink for a specific page to allow me to have 'fake categories' to organize my pages.

I need this feature because I use some plugins that are included/excluded for specific pages and posts.  It's easy for me to use wildcards when configuring the plugin settings if I can group pages under a category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parent page *Not existing category* with the subpage *My page title*.

For more information take a look at [Organizing your pages](https://wordpress.org/support/article/pages/#organizing-pages).